# pre get posts not working with Tribe Events

Tags: query, pre-get-posts, the-events-calendar

I am using the events calendar by modern tribe.
They claim this defaults to showing events in the main loop by event date. This is not what I am seeing on my site. I downgraded the plugin and it works by event date as expected, but the newer version is showing the posts by published date. this is causing issues with imported data.

I have tried a few conditional tags, but none of them actually work as expected. it is as if the conditions are never met. However, and this is important, if i remove the conditional tag for checking if its NOT a standard post, the events all show up by event date (but without the standard posts, as you would expect to happen)

not clear what the issue is here, help!

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_events_to_main_loop', 10, 1 );
function add_events_to_main_loop( $query ) {
   if ($query->is_main_query() ) {
       $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
     if (get_post_type() !== 'post') {
        $query->set('meta_key', '_EventStartDate' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query',
            array(
                'key'     => '_EventStartDate',
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
                'value'   => $value,
                'type'    => 'numeric',
            )
        );
   }
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'tribe_events' ) );
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd ask the plugin authors for help if you haven't already, and it might be worth diffing the last version of the plugin that works and the current version to see if you can see what they've changed that's breaking things. Can you stick with the old version in the short term?

Comment: It sounds to me like something is triggering showing your events as regular posts and not actually events, or at least the code that controls the ordering. I wouldn't know where to look for that specifically.

Comment: hi mate, yeah i tried all of this and you are correct, there is code which adds these posts as 'posts' to the main loop. so, my above code will not work as the conditional statement is not being met. I did actually roll it back, and the old version does indeed list the events in the loop by event date. the reason for this faffing is i am dealing with imported data. the plugin devs have not been very helpful im sorry to say.